# What would be the proper way to set the right permissions on a folder of files after transferring them to your VM?

Tags: permissions, rsync

Right now, I'm getting a permissions denied error on a csv file even after doing `chmod +rwx` on that file. I had to set permissions on some other files on the VM, and those worked. This one doesn't work, however.
I think it's also worth pointing out that using `rsync` to transfer the files and folders hasn't been working out well.

```
rsync -rvze "ssh -p 2222" /path/to/localfolder me@localhost:/path/to/remote
```

Many files failed to open due to permissions problems. The error ends with

```
rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(820) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Now, when I did transfer the files to begin with, it was under a different user on that VM. Could that have something to do with these two problems?
**edit** after doing an `ls -l`. I can now see that I'm not the same user as the owner on the VM.  The first one is on my regular OS.
                                                                             total 12

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users 4004 Jul 24 07:19 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users  288 Apr 23 05:48 some.ini
-rwxr----- 1 me users 2008 Jul 30 03:04 ex.csv
```

total 12

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 d d 4004 Jul 24 07:19 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 d d  288 Apr 23 05:48 some.ini
-rwxr-xr-x 1 d d   11 Jul 25 03:27 ex.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a permissions denied error doing what with the CSV? Can you post the `ls -l` output of both sides?

You would only get a permission denied error if your directory permissions prevent you from writing files. Without the `-a` option, rsync won't transfer permissions at all and will create the files with default permissions, owned by the running user (me@localhost in this case).

Comment: Leaving out the `-a` option in the rsync command I posted told me some bytes were transferred and received, but then I could see that the contents of the files on the VM were not updated.

Comment: Each Linux system has their own, separate set of users which map to user IDs. The first user ID usually defaults to 1000. `ls -ln` will show you the user ID. `rsync -a` will sync the user ID number, not the name. When you reran rsync, did you delete the file, so permissions could be created from scratch? Is `d` the same user as `me` from the original post?